# ionic: HTML5 audio tag not working on iOS 11

Tags: ios, html, audio, ionic-framework, ios11

I am developing an ionic framework test app which streams audio from a server using the HTML5 audio tag. I've been testing it in some Android and iOS devices and it works just fine.

Today I got an iOS 11 device to test and I found that the stream does not work. I created a simple web to test the device with safari and worked. I uploaded the app to ionic view and worked too.

Is there something new on iOS 11 that disables streamings on apps?
Is it something with the HTML5 audio tag?

Comment: What format audio file are you trying to play? I had some similar issues on iOS with the `video` tag and it ended up being that I had to convert the video for iOS and do some other stuff on the server-side.

Comment: Maybe duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46486307/html-5-audioelement-wont-play-mp3-livestreams-in-safari-on-ios-11-devices

Comment: The audio comes from a stream that I do not own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding type="audio/mpeg" to the audio tag.